# Is there a minimum number of candidates for the current SO election?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Looking at the current list of nominees it looks quite empty and one prior nomination has been withdrawn.

Is there a minimum number of candidates for the current election to go ahead?
In case there is just one or two candidates will the election go ahead or will it be postponed/cancelled?

I'm aware that for many of the other sites there probably aren't that many candidates and current moderators, but SO has quite a few moderators. Is there are list of rules that apply to this election?

Comment: don't worry, a lot of candidates are coming .. we will easily reach around 20 (they are all preparing their answers )

Comment: @TemaniAfif *Crosses fingers and toes*

Comment: @TemaniAfif Then why are you wasting time here on Meta? Get busy! :-p

Comment: no, not for me :) I don't want to handle a ton of custom flag .. I want to raise them and blame moderators for not being active :p

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is a minimum. In order for the election to be held, there must be at least 3 nominees.

Why 3? Well, there are 2 moderator slots available, and the minimum number of nominees is defined the number of available slots plus 1. (This gives you at least the chance to make a *choice* in the election.)

If there are fewer than 3 nominees, the election will be terminated and no new moderators will be added to [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). A new election will have to be held later. (But I still think it is premature to worry about this. I think it's quite unlikely that we'll have fewer than 3 nominees.)

Comment: Please can we have a "none of the above" option.

Comment: @Ian If there's someone you think would be a good moderator, you should encourage them to nominate themselves. You would probably be eligible yourself, if you were interested...

Comment: No chance I would wish to be a moderator until the company starts careing more  about quality then maximise the stock price when their is a IPO.